# R data.table value from previous row with conditional statement

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to update a data table value depending on whether it meets a criteria and return either the value from another column or the value from the row above (same column).
As an example:

```
library( data.table )
data <- data.table( Col1 = 1:5, Col2 = letters[1:5] )
```

I would like to return the following:

```
data2 <- data.table( Col1= 1:5, Col2= letters[1:5], Col3= c("NA", "NA", "3", "3", "3"))
```

I have read the `?shift` help page but I can't adapt it to using a conditional statement and returning a value in the same column. To get my desired outcome I have tried:

```
data[ , ( Col3 ) := ifelse( get( Col2 ) == "c", get( Col1 ) , shift( Col3 ))]
```

I would be grateful for some advice.

*Please ignore my use of `get()` for this example as I am aware it may not be the best approach.

Comment: It's not very data.table-ish, but with `library(zoo)`, you can do `data[Col1==3, Col3 := Col1][, Col3 := na.locf(Col3, na.rm=FALSE)]`. I suspect there's a more idiomatic way with data.table, though.

Comment: The next version (v1.9.8) will very likely have quite efficient implementations for these kinds of operations.

Comment: Thanks @Frank . I have just noticed that when I use this on a larger data set for example: `data3 <- data.table(Col1= 1:10, Col2 = c(letters[1:5],letters[1:5]))` the values in Col3 don't update as expected. In row 8, Col3 I would expect to see the value 8. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3740289 Oh, oops, that's just because I typed the condition wrong. `data3[Col2=='c', Col3 := Col1][, Col3 := na.locf(Col3, na.rm=FALSE)]` Notice that `Col2=='c'` now appears at the start. You can run this in pieces to debug `data3[Col2=='c', Col3 := Col1]` then `data3[, Col3 := na.locf(Col3, na.rm=FALSE)]` examining the data after each step.

Comment: Yes I should have spotted that one actually. It works nicely now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This old, so far unanswered question has been revived recently.

As of today I am aware of the following approaches:

#### 1. `zoo::na.locf()`

According to [Frank's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786372/r-data-table-value-from-previous-row-with-conditional-statement#comment55341701_33786372):

```
data3 <- data.table(Col1= 1:10, Col2 = c(letters[1:5],letters[1:5]))
data3[Col2=='c', Col3 := Col1][, Col3 := zoo::na.locf(Col3, na.rm=FALSE)]
data3[]
```

> ```
>     Col1 Col2 Col3
>  1:    1    a   NA
>  2:    2    b   NA
>  3:    3    c    3
>  4:    4    d    3
>  5:    5    e    3
>  6:    6    a    3
>  7:    7    b    3
>  8:    8    c    8
>  9:    9    d    8
> 10:   10    e    8
> ```

#### 2. `cumsum()`

```
data3 <- data.table(Col1= 1:10, Col2 = c(letters[1:5],letters[1:5]))
data3[, Col3 := Col1[which(Col2 == "c")], by = cumsum(Col2 == "c")]
data3[]
```

> ```
>     Col1 Col2 Col3
>  1:    1    a   NA
>  2:    2    b   NA
>  3:    3    c    3
>  4:    4    d    3
>  5:    5    e    3
>  6:    6    a    3
>  7:    7    b    3
>  8:    8    c    8
>  9:    9    d    8
> 10:   10    e    8
> ```

Comment: @user:10225690 In response to your request, I have added an answer.